# Getting data into Julia session?

Tags: interoperability, external-calls, julia

Mathematica has a way of [integrating](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureJuliaForExternalEvaluate.html) with Julia, and automatically convert Julia outputs into Mathematica objects (Julia seems to have nice [support](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices/LowRankApprox.jl) for low-rank approximation). What is the best way to use Mathematica matrices as Julia inputs?

For instance I can get get trace of Cholesky factor as follows

```
FindExternalEvaluators["Julia"]
jj[cmd_] := ExternalEvaluate["Julia", cmd];
jj["using LinearAlgebra;A=[2 1;1 2];tr(cholesky(A).U)"]
```

But a more useful scenario would be to try it on a `A` like below:

```
d = 4000;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}];
A = A + Transpose[A] + 2. Sqrt[d] IdentityMatrix[d];
Tr@CholeskyDecomposition@A
```

Answer (score 10):

Fortunately, the Wolfram team had done the hard part for us. We don't have to build interface to call julia (in most cases).

First, start a session:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Julia"]
```

Load your libraries:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "using LinearAlgebra;"]
```

Build your function in Julia:

```
juliaFn1 = ExternalFunction[session, "f(x)=tr(cholesky(x).U)"]
```

Use it as a normal function in Mathematica:

```
juliaFn1[A]
```

Note in this simple example with `d = 4000`, Mathematica was orders of magnitude faster and the performance of Julia will diminish because of sending/receiving large arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It looks like it takes 20 seconds to get a 64MB array into Julia this way. This is orders of magnitudes slower than what's possible (ie, what Ray does with Arrow https://docs.ray.io/en/releases-1.11.1/ray-core/serialization.html   )....I would guess there's an inefficient single thread serialization/deserialization process somewhere

Answer (score 3):

@Ben's answer above is obviously very convenient. I just wanted to mention that, had that capability not been available already, you could parse and reformat the matrix yourself, and then use e.g. `StringTemplate` to generate the line of Julia code:

Here is a simple helper function that really just encapsulates the appropriate choices of delimiters for StringRiffle, which does all the reformatting in one go:

```
ClearAll[juliaMat]
juliaMat[a_?MatrixQ] := StringRiffle[a, {"[", "; ", "]"}, " "]

a = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; RandomInteger[10, {4, 3}]];
juliaMat[a]

(* Out: "[1 4 0; 7 0 0; 8 6 0; 4 1 8]" *)
```

You can then insert that result where you need it in  your command line either using `StringJoin`, or using a template expression as follows:

```
StringTemplate["using LinearAlgebra;A=<*juliaMat[#1]*>;tr(cholesky(A).U)"][a]

(* Out: 
  "using LinearAlgebra;A=[1 4 0; 7 0 0; 8 6 0; 4 1 8];tr(cholesky(A).U)"
*)
```